# WiFi card not detected by Windows first time after restarting from Ubuntu in dual-boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, windows-10, wifi-driver

The following is my setup:

Asus K551LN i5 laptop (dual boot), Windows 10 Home (fast startup disabled), Ubuntu 15.10 amd64 (dual boot)

This laptop has the MediaTek MT7630E wifi card for which the linux kernel doesn't have an out-of-the-box driver (at present and for kernel version of Ubuntu above).

I installed and used the driver source at https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1796 which works fine in Ubuntu.

The problem is that whenever I then restart Ubuntu (from the UI), and boot back into Windows, the Wifi card is not detected by Windows.

This is just for the first reboot and there's no problem if I reboot into Windows again (from the UI). Device manager shows some issue with the Wifi card and Bluetooth device the first time. Scanning for hardware changes, doesn't do anything, but if I disable and enable it again manually from Device Manager - it comes up fine without needing to reboot again.